# Why does netcat -v send extra X packets?

Tags: netcat, tcpdump, syslog

I'm using netcat 1.218 on Ubuntu 22.04 to generate test syslog packets, and I noticed an odd behavior I can't explain.  When I use the `-v` flag, netcat sends 2 additional packets containing the letter `X`.  Without `-v`, it sends only one packet, as expected, but rsyslog does not recognize the input.

Example command:

```
echo "<13>1 2024-02-28T04:07:00 hostname appname - - - message body" | nc -w 0 localhost 514 -u
```

tcpdump output:

```
05:08:02.735724 lo    In  IP localhost.37754 > localhost.514: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 62
E..Z..@.@.`..........z...F.Y<13>1 2024-02-28T04:07:00 hostname appname - - - message body
```

The same command with `-v` added:

```
05:08:58.863527 lo    In  IP localhost.56439 > localhost.514:  (invalid)
E...N.@.@..E.........w...   ..X
05:08:58.863577 lo    In  IP localhost.56439 > localhost.514:  (invalid)
E...N.@.@..D.........w...   ..X
05:08:58.863764 lo    In  IP localhost.56439 > localhost.514: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 62
E..ZN.@.@............w...F.Y<13>1 2024-02-28T04:07:00 hostname appname - - - message body
```

DebugFormat output from rsyslog with the `-v` included:

```
Debug line with all properties:
FROMHOST: 'localhost', fromhost-ip: '127.0.0.1', HOSTNAME: 'X', PRI: 13,
syslogtag '', programname: '', APP-NAME: '-', PROCID: '-', MSGID: '-',
TIMESTAMP: 'Feb 28 05:09:35', STRUCTURED-DATA: '-',
msg: ''
escaped msg: ''
inputname: imudp rawmsg: 'X'
$!:
$.:
$/:

Debug line with all properties:
FROMHOST: 'localhost', fromhost-ip: '127.0.0.1', HOSTNAME: 'X', PRI: 13,
syslogtag '', programname: '', APP-NAME: '-', PROCID: '-', MSGID: '-',
TIMESTAMP: 'Feb 28 05:09:35', STRUCTURED-DATA: '-',
msg: ''
escaped msg: ''
inputname: imudp rawmsg: 'X'
$!:
$.:
$/:

Debug line with all properties:
FROMHOST: 'localhost', fromhost-ip: '127.0.0.1', HOSTNAME: 'localhost', PRI: 13,
syslogtag '', programname: '', APP-NAME: '', PROCID: '-', MSGID: '-',
TIMESTAMP: 'Feb 28 05:09:35', STRUCTURED-DATA: '-',
msg: '2024-02-28T04:07:00 hostname appname - - - message body'
escaped msg: '2024-02-28T04:07:00 hostname appname - - - message body'
inputname: imudp rawmsg: '<13>1 2024-02-28T04:07:00 hostname appname - - - message body'
$!:
$.:
$/:
```